# Theorem 2.22 from RCA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

I read this interesting result from Rudin's book but I would like to clarify some confusing moments.

As I understood $(\mathbb{R}^1, +)$ is group and $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is subgroup.

He considers cosets $E_r=r+\mathbb{Q}$ for $r\in \mathbb{R}$. Since $E_r\neq \varnothing$ then by axiom of choice we can costruct set $E$ which contains only one element from each $E_r$.

Question 1: I am not sure that $(E+r)\cap (E+s)=\varnothing$ for $r,s\in \mathbb{Q}$, $r\neq s$. Let's consider cosets $\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}$ and $1+\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}$ and let $E$ contains $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}+1$ from the first and second cosets, respectively. But $E+1$ also contains $\sqrt{2}+1$. So we see that $E\cap (E+1)\neq \varnothing$.

Question 2: Suppose that I have mistake in my previous question. Let $y$ and $z$ lie in the same coset of $Q$? Where's the contradiction?

Question 3: Why such $y$ exists? I am about point $(b)$.

Would be very thankful for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1: The cosets $\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}$ and $1+\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}$ are actually the same.  If $x=\sqrt{2}+q\in\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}$, then $q-1$ is also rational, so $x=1+\sqrt{2}+(q-1)$ is also in $1+\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}$, and similarly conversely.

Question 2: By assumption, $E$ contains exactly one point from each coset.  So if $y,z\in E$ are two distinct points which are in the same coset, this is a contradiction.

Question 3: Again, by assumption, $E$ contains exactly one point from each coset.  In particular, it contains exactly one point from the coset $x+\mathbb{Q}$, and this is the point we call $y$.

Comment: Yes I am agree with that $\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}$ and $1+\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}$ are the same. But what cosets Rudin considers? He didn't mention nothing about this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The set $E$ is assumed to contain exactly one point from each coset.  That is, for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $E\cap (x+\mathbb{Q})$ contains exactly one point.  Note, though, that different values of $x$ can give the same set $x+\mathbb{Q}$, and then $E$ still contains only one point from this set.

Comment: I mean the following: Consider coset $\sqrt{2}+Q$. We take some element from this coset and put into $E$. What about cosets $1+\sqrt{2}+Q$ or $2+\sqrt{2}+Q$? Can we take some element from them? Or not (because of they are the same)?

Comment: We don't take an additional element from them, because we already have an element from them.  We want $E$ to have exactly one point from each coset, so we shouldn't add more points to $E$ from cosets it already contains a point of.

Comment: I guess that I understood you. Since $\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}=1+\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}$ then $E\cap(\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q})=E\cap(1+\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q})$. So from same cosets we take the same element. Right? P.S. Sorry for English :)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Let me ask you one more question from proof: Since $H$ is countable union of closed sets then $H$ is $F_{\sigma}$ set then we can consider $m(H)$. Right?

Comment: That's correct.